FFmpeg: To trim a video using 'trim' and specify time using HH:MM:SS format
FFmpeg 7.0.1. I want to understand whether it is possible to trim a video using trim and to specify start and end time using the HH:MM:SS format instead of just seconds.
That is, the following command trims a video from 5s to 10s:
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf trim=5:10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS output.mp4

But if I try to specify start and end time using HH:MM:SS format, FFmpeg returns an error:
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf trim='00:00:05':'00:00:15',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS output.mp4

ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf trim=00\:00\:05:00\:00\:15,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS output.mp4


Output file is empty, nothing was encoded(check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)

Is it possible to fix it? (A guy on Super User suggested trim='00\:00\:05':'00\:00\:15' or trim=00\\:00\\:05:00\\:00\\:15, but I receive the same error message.)
Side questions

To keep the first 5 seconds and drop everything else, I can use ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf trim=end=5 output.mp4. But how to keep only the last 5 seconds?

To drop frist 5 seconds, I can use ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf trim=start=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS output.mp4. But how to drop the last 5 seconds?



If you want to trim using time you would have to use -ss and -to ...ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:15 -i input.mp4

You'll have to quote and escape both.
trim='00\:00\:05':'00\:00\:15'
or double escape,
trim=00\\:00\\:05:00\\:00\\:15

Thanks, but neither of these two solution works for me (e.g., ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf trim='00\:00\:05':'00\:00\:15',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS output.mp4). I receive the same error message. What might be a reason? ffmpeg version 7.0.1

Add -report and rerun. Share report.

I added it to the question.

The video itself was created using ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -r 10 -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=500 -vf setpts=N/10/TB -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p input.mp4
